# Do I always need to rebuild the project containing references to sub project's dll, if sub projects are updated?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a solution containing 4 class library projects and one "web site" project. The web site project contains references to the 3 class library projects, whenever I make changes in any of the class library projects, the only option I see is to rebuild the web site which takes a lot of time.

Is there any option that I can only update the dll references and the changes are reflected in the web site project ?

Comment: any speed difference if (after changing the class library project(s)) you just build (not rebuild) the web site project instead of rebuilding the whole solution?  Building the web site project should be enough, as it'll have referenced projects also build, and the ones that haven't updated can (relatively quickly) finish since they don't need to actually build anything, and the one(s) that did update will then build again as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* rebuild everything, yes. When you change one of the class libraries, that could subtly change how the code is called. There are obvious changes like removing a method that your web site is relying on, but there are sneakier ones like adding an overload - so that the code will still compile, but have a different effect.

I don't know of any way to tell Visual Studio *not* to do a rebuild when a dependency changes... I would personally look at finding a way to make the overall build faster instead.

If you're doing a lot of work in the class libraries and you don't actually *need* the web site for the moment, you could always unload that project until you need to run the whole site again.

Comment: I am running the web site through IIS. Now, I have seen that, I only need to build the changed class library only. It is not required to rebuild the website again. One mistake I did was, I added the class library's references through the browse tab instead of the projects tab.